# grep the exact block of lines (content of file1) from file2

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have two files, `file1` and `file2`.

The sample content of `file1` is:

```
A B
C D
E F
G H
```

and the content of `file2` is like:

```
A B
few other lines
E F
few more other lines
A B
C D
E F
G H
few more other lines
G H
```

So I want to search the whole block of `file1` content in `file2` only.
This means the output should contain only these lines:

```
A B
C D
E F
G H
```

please note that :- only the lines which are coming together , should be the part of output.

Comment: I don't get your question.  If you only want to print the exact content of `file1` and nothing else, just use `cat file1`.

Comment: @Wildcard he wants to see if file2 contains exactly the same content as file1.  Think about it as if looking for a specific chapter in a book

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this as the "set members" are made up of multiple lines (I didn't spot that at first), which is slightly more complex than single lines handled by the accepted answer to the proposed duplicate question.

Comment: This is **not** about sets. If you want to mark this as a duplicate, at least find another question about multi-line regexps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`grep` is pretty stupid when it comes to multiline patterns, but translating all newline characters `\n` of both the pattern and the text to search into NUL characters `\0` before comparing them fixes this. Translating `\0` in the output back to `\n` is obviously also needed.

Here's your command, assuming that `file1` contains the pattern you want to search in `file2`:

```
grep -aof <(tr '\n' '\0' < file1) <(tr '\n' '\0' < file2) | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Example output for your given files:

```
A B
C D
E F
G H
```

Explanation:

- `<(tr '\n' '\0' < file1)` creates a FIFO/named pipe/temporary file-like object that equals `file1`, but with all newline characters translated to NUL characters.
- `<(tr '\n' '\0' < file2)` does the same, but for `file2`.
- `grep -f PATTERN_FILE INPUT_FILE` searches for the pattern(s) from `PATTERN_FILE` in `INPUT_FILE`.
- The `-a` flag of `grep` enables matching on binary files. This is needed because otherwise it would skip files that contain non-printable characters like `\0`.
- The `-o` flag of `grep` makes it print only the matching sequence, not the whole line where it has been found.
- `| tr '\0' '\n'` translates all NUL characters from the output of the command on the left side back to newline characters.

Answer (score 6):

The following is clumsy, but works with GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v RS="$(<file1)" '{print RT}' file2
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun in pure bash

```
mapfile -t <file1
while read line ; do
    [ "$line" = "${MAPFILE[i++]}" ] || { ["$line" = "$MAPFILE" ] && i=1 || i=0; }
    [ $i -eq ${#MAPFILE[*]} ] && { printf "%s\n" "${MAPFILE[@]}"; i=0; }
done <file2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit more elegant `grep` + `perl` :

```
$ grep -Pzo "$(perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g' file1.txt )"  file2.txt                    
A B
C D
E F
G H
```

However, there is one big catch. If there is a trailing newline in `file1` , the pattern will not be correct, in other words: `A B\nC D\nE F\nG H\n\n`.

( Special thanks @terdon for providing the perl part )

As costas noted , one can use `perl -0pe 's/\n(\n+$)?/\\n/g'`  in place of the other `perl` command to avoid the trailing newline in the `file1.txt`

Comment: If there is a trailing newline and that is not the OP want to find `perl -0pe 's/\n(\n+$)?/\\n/g'`. Without `-0` the `g` regex modificator is extra.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure what you want the output to be, but it's easy to do with languages that are not exclusively line-oriented (especially if both files can be read into memory). Here's a python script that'll tell you how many matches there are.

```
import sys
find = open(sys.argv[1]).read()
hay = open(sys.argv[2]).read()
print("The text occurs", hay.count(find), "times")
```

You want to print `file1` as many times as it matches? Replace the last line with this:

```
print(find * hay.count(find))
```

You could pack everything into a commandline call or alias, if you really want to:

```
python -c 'import sys; print("The text occurs", open(sys.argv[2]).read().count(open(sys.argv[1]).read()), "times")' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -lir 'A B \n D C \n whatever' ./folder_to_search
```

the result will be all files with exact text match

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using python (tested with `python3 3.5.2`, with no complaints from `pylint3 1.5.6`):

```
""" Locate entire file contents contiguous in other file """

import sys
import re
from mmap import mmap, PROT_READ

def memmap(name):
    """ Return memoryview of readonly mmap """
    with open(name, 'rb') as file:
        return memoryview(mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=PROT_READ))

def finder(needle, haystack):
    """ Return iterator """
    return re.compile(re.escape(needle)).finditer(haystack)

print(tuple(finder(*(memmap(name) for name in sys.argv[1:3]))))
```

The handling of command line arguments via `sys.argv` is admittedly simplistic. You could do many other things with the return value of `finder` on the two `memoryview` objects you pass in, besides pass it to `tuple`. Each `SRE_Match` item yielded by the iterator returned by `finder` has a variety of methods, a sampling of which is summarized in the `print` output (the `span`, for example, tells the byte range of each match).